# Alternative proof of metric space closure for Rudin 2.27

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I'm using the definitions from Rudin's Principles of Math. Analysis

Definitions:

1. If $X$ is a metric space, $E\subset X$, and if $E'$ deonotes the set of all limit points of $E \in X$, the the closure of $E$ is the set $E^{*}= E \cup E'$
2. A point $p$ is a *limit point* of the set $A$ if every neighborhood of p contains a point $q\neq p$ such that $q\in A$
3. A set is *closed* if every limit point of $A$ is a point of $A$

$\ $

> Theorem
> If $X$ is a metric space, $E\subset X$, then $E^*$ is closed.
>
> Proof. We must show that any limit point $p$ of $E$ lies in $E$. Now any neighborhood $N$ of $p$ contains some $q∈E$. Since $N$ is open, $N$ contains some neighborhood $M$ of $q$, and since $q∈E$, M contains some $r∈E$. Thus $r∈M ⊆ N$, so every neighborhood $N$ of $p$ contains a point $r∈E$, so $p∈E$.

This is not Rudin's proof in the book. I found it on an [online errata linked](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/ug.hndts/m104_Rudin_notes.pdf) (11th comment on page 3).

Is the following understanding of this of this proof correct? Thanks in advanced.

We must show that any limit point $p$ of $E^*$ lies in $E^*.$ Assume that $p$ is a limit point of $E^*$. Now any neighborhood $N$ of $p$ contains some $q∈E^*.$ Either $q \in E$ or $q\in E'$

If $q\in E$ then by the definition above p is a limit point of $E$ and hence $p\in E'$.

Or $q\in E'$ and there exists some neighborhood $M$ of $q$, such that $M \subset E$ such that it contains a point $r \in E$. It follows that $r \in N \cap E$, therefore $p \in E^*$

Comment: That's mostly correct. But I have a few quibbles. $q\in E$ doesn't prove p is a limit point as a smaller nbrhd might not have any points of E. You wish to show a nbhd containing limits points of E implies it contain points of E. Second how does it follow that $M\subset E$.  You didn't claim why that would be.

Comment: Also I don't see that proof is significantly different that the proof Rudin gives.

Comment: "Second how does it follow that M⊂E. You didn't claim why that would be."  The answer being: The idea being that you can find a nbhd with a small enough radius so that nbhd is entirely in E.  It's intuitive, but it must be stated.

Comment: @fleablood Yeah that's what I was thinking that there would be a small enough neighborhood. Thanks anyway though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If q∈E
then by the definition above p is a limit point of E and hence p∈E′"

Not quite. $q$ is only one point and we haven't shown *every* neighborhood contains a point of $E$-- we've only shown *that* one did.

Instead the idea is to show that if $q \in E'$ then there is a third point $r$ also in the neighborhood so either $q$ is the point, or there is a third point $r$ in the neighborhood.

.

"Or q∈E′
and there exists some neighborhood M of q, such that M⊂E"

Why is $M \subset E$?  You need to explain why.  Now, I'll confess, I always did a thing where I took a radius that was the $e= \min (d(q,p), radius N- d(q,p))$ and show a neighborhood of $B_e(q) \subset E$.  But I see this proof did something quite a bit simpler and clever.

$N$ is open and $q \in N$ so by the definition of open there is neighborhood $M\subset E$ around $q$.  And being a neighborhood around a limit point $q$ of $E$ there is an $r\in E$ in the neighborhood $M\subset E$ and we are done.

such that it contains a point r∈E. It follows that r∈N∩E, therefore p∈E∗

Comment: Yes. Take it out of the context of metrics. It holds for all spaces........+1